# Returning array to from static method to main method. Array printing gibberish

Tags: java, arrays, methods, static

Hey all I am stuck with this homework assignment and hoping to print numbers in the main that were inputted from a static method.  I have tried two options....this one just prints gibberish

Option 1:   But this prints gibberish.

public class GetNumbers {

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    
    
    System.out.println(" Congratulations, you entered two valid floats:" + getTwoFloats());
}
// Return method to obtain two values from user============================================ 
private static float [] getTwoFloats() {
    float [] myResults =new float[2];
    Scanner readInput = new Scanner(System.in);

    do { 
        System.out.print("\nEnter two floats separated by a space: ");
       try { 
        float myFloat1 = readInput.nextFloat(); 
        // waits for user input 
        float myFloat2 = readInput.nextFloat(); 
        // waits for user input if you are here, the floats were good, you 
        // are done, break out from loop 
       } catch (final InputMismatchException e) { 
        System.out.println("You have entered an invalid input. Try again."); 
        readInput.nextLine(); 
        // discard non-float input 
        continue; 
        // keep looping until you found right one 
       }
       return myResults;
      } while (true);
```

}

Answer (score 0):

The toString impl of arrays is not what you think it is. Calling `System.out.println(x)` where x is just some object is shorthand for `System.out.println(x.toString())`.

You can either write your own, or use `Arrays.toString(x)` instead: `System.out.println(Arrays.toString(getTwoFloats())`.

In general arrays are low level constructs with many annoying downsides and few upsides. You shouldn't use them for this sort of purpose. a `List<Double>` would be a better idea.

NB: `float` is completely useless. Use `double`.